# Discord.py @bot.event

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I have a script that uses both `@bot.event` and `@bot.command()`. The problem is that when I have a `@bot.event` waiting the `@bot.command()` will not run.

Here is my code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot Is Ready And Online!")
    
async def react(message): 
    if message.content == "Meeting":
        await message.add_reaction("")

@bot.command()
async def info(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello, thanks for testing out our bot. ~ techNOlogics")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def meet(ctx,time):
    if ctx.message.author.name == "techNOlogics":
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
        await ctx.send("**Meeting at " + time + " today!** React if you read.")

@bot.event ##THIS ONE HOLDS UP THE WHOLE SCRIPT
async def on_message(message):
    await react(message)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using a mixture of the `on_message` event with commands, you'll want to add `await bot.process_commands(message)`, like so:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    # rest of code
```

As said in the docs:

> This function processes the commands that have been registered to the bot and other groups. Without this coroutine, none of the commands will be triggered.
>
> If you choose to override the on_message() event, you then you should invoke this coroutine as well.

---

**References:**

- [`Bot.process_commands()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands)
- [`on_message()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message)