# discord.py: on_message(message) dont works since a few days

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

Since a few days two of my bots dont react on_message(message). In console there show no error.

for example a simple badword script. since last week it worked fine. but now ... no output.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    bad_words = ['badword1','badword2','badword3','badword4','badword5','badword6']
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    for word in bad_words:
        if 0 < message.content.count(word) < 2:
            await message.channel.send("{}, bitte achte auf Deine Wortwahl.".format(message.author.mention))
            await message.delete()
            break
    else:
        await bot.process_commands(message)
```

I don't know what is wrong. i hope someone can help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're some updates about `Intents` in the discord.py 1.5.x. Intents are like permissions, you have to define it to use some events like `on_message` and getting members, channels etc. You need to define it before defining `bot = discord.Bot(prefix='')` to get guilds, channels etc.

```py
import discord
intents = discord.Intents().all()
bot = discord.Bot(prefix='', intents=intents)
```

For more information about intents, you can look at the [API References](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents).

Comment: Thank you for your Reply. Oh, I guess I forgot to mention that. I have already added these lines after my research. Now, on_member_join and and on_member_remove are now possible . Only on react (message) and on_message (message) do not work. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Can you edit your question with your `on_reaction_add` event or whatever event that's not working?

Comment: i have add the react(message) Event.

Comment: both are not working since a few days. and no error in console.

Comment: There's no event named `react`?

Comment: That was the template  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62076257/discord-py-bot-event

Comment: It's not an event, it's just a coroutine function that reacts to a message, so it's meaningless to put `@bot.event` at the start. It's not an event. You have to call the function for it to work.

Comment: i have the coroutine react changed to the event on_message. this works now. :) ty for that. Have you an idea why the other on message event will no more works ?

Comment: This was my newes try:

`
@bot.event
async def on_message(message): 
    bad_words = ["badword1","badword2"]
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    if any(bad_word in message.content.lower() for bad_word in bad_words):
       channel = message.channel
       msguser = message.author.name
       await channel.send("{}, bitte achte auf Deine Wortwahl.".format(msguser))
    else:
       await bot.process_commands(message)
`

But it dosn`t want to work.